# Start Menu and Search malfunctioning?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, start-menu, windows-search

I noticed this randomly start happening on my laptop yesterday, where for some reason, when I open the start menu or search, it starts acting like the up arrow key is being help down:

[image]

I have no keyboard or mouse macros set or anything, and it *only* happens with the Start Menu and search, everything else continues working normally.

Currently, the only way to resolve the issue is by rebooting it - does anyone know what could be causing this problem, and how I could fix it?

Comment: I would upgrade your installation to 21H1 and see if that solves the problem

Comment: Does it happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: Maybe only informational, but have you  tried installing software to see if the UP arrow is actually being detected as a key press when this happens?

Comment: @Ramhound It's already fully up to date (the little version indicator thing in the bottom right is incorrect, I have 21H1 build 19043.1110)

Comment: @harrymc Yes it does

Comment: General troubleshooting: Run [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) followed by [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Answer (score -1):

Does restarting Cortana do anything?

try this PowerShell script too Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
reinstalls default windows apps(Cortana included)

do always remember to make ur system restores!